# Is there any method to upload images to Amazon S3 in meteor js?

Tags: meteor, meteor-slingshot

I have used `CollectionFS` and `Slingshot`, but none of them worked. Is their any other alternative?

Comment: You should specify what is "not working", and show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend Slingshot and I have had good success with it in the past. I have also heard good things about CollectionFS, but never used it.

Maybe try posting a SO question about what you aren't able to get working.

Comment: CollectionFS is deprecated, but Slingshot works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Slingshot to upload documents from client to S3. It helps in preventing over loading server. Must be something wrong with the code. Providing more details will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
let fileObj=new upload($(evt.target)[0].files[0])
fileObj.start(function(url){
//do something with url
})
```

**upload class**

```
import {Slingshot} from 'meteor/edgee:slingshot'

class upload{
 constructor(fileObj){
this._file=fileObj;
this._uploadInstance=new Slingshot.Upload("s3upload");
 }



start(cb){
this._uploadInstance.send(this._file,(error,url)=>{
  console.log(error);
  if(error)
    throw new Meteor.Error('upload-error',this._uploadInstance.xhr.response)

  cb(url)

})
}
}

export default upload
```

Its a working solution using slingshot package
Thanks
Cheers